# How to unlock an iPhone 3GS with 05.16.05?

Tags: jailbreak, iphone, unlock

I had a perfectly working unlocked and jailbroken iPhone 3GS, but of course I had to go ahead and try to get iOS 5 on it. I didn't know I need to preserve my baseband while updating it, so now ultrasn0w will not unlock it for me and I'm left without a phone line.

Is there any way to unlock an iPhone 3GS with 05.16.05 baseband? If not, is there any expected change that will allow me to do so?

Comment: Currently no. You've lost your unlock till ultrasnow releases a version capable of handling the new baseband. No ETA on that.

Comment: @cksum is anyone working on it?

Comment: Of course! They have likely been working on from the first iOS 5 beta release.

Comment: Is there anyone in-the-know who can tell if that's likely to be released any time soon? I wonder if I'm at the point of buying a new phone since this one isn't usable.

Comment: No. The people working on it don't put out a timeline to release. When it's out, it's out. This is why the net is littered with notices NOT TO UPDATE without checking first. I suggest you take your discussion here: http://blog.iphone-dev.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By now it is possible to **down**-grade your baseband - at least for the iPhone 3G and 3GS (unfortunately not 4/S) - from the iPad's 06.15 to 05.13.04 (un-lockable) thanks to the great work of the iPhone Dev Team:

> The iPhone Dev Team is happy to announce a baseband downgrade option in redsn0w for those who are using the iPad’s 06.15 baseband on the iPhone3G or iPhone3GS.
>
> Typically you’d have the 06.15 baseband if you unlock with ultrasn0w but updated your iPhone baseband past 05.13.04.  With this new capability, you can now downgrade specifically from 06.15 to 05.13.04 (even if you never had 05.13.04 on that device before).  This gives you the best of both worlds: ultrasn0w compatibility and a normal iPhone baseband with full GPS and the ability to use stock IPSWs again.

See [this post](http://blog.iphone-dev.org/post/26534086824/baseband-freedom) on their blog.

Comment: Are you saying that the answer to the OP's question is basically no, but the workaround is to downgrade the baseband and then unlock - not upgrade again?

Comment: @bmike: You cannot unlock BB 05.16.05, but you can "upgrade" to the iPad BB 06.15 - but then you lose GPS and push-notifications. What is new now is that you can *down*-grade from the iPad BB 06.15 to the iPhone BB 05.13.04, which you can unlock. So you now can have iOS 5.1.1 with fully functional BB 05.13.04 and unlock.

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much! My iPhone was a heavy iPod for months!

Comment: (Spent all my rep on this bounty, so I can't give an upvote, but I will once I can)

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this by accident, but if you are still having issues there is now an [iOS 5 jailbreak out](http://www.jailbreaknation.com/) - although tethered, it will do what you want.